# Action Delegate as a Property

Tags: c#

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to define this property for my class. The best way I can explain what I'm trying to do is pass an Action off from one class as another class's own. Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class Data {

    private float value;

    public Action<float> ValueChanged; // actual delegate

    public void UpdateValue(float delta){
        value += delta;
        ValueChange?.Invoke(delta);
    }
}


public class Controller {

    private Data data; // initialized elsewhere...

    public Action<float> DataChanged => data.ValueChanged; // pass delegate as our own, this does not work
}


public class SomeOtherClass {

    private Controller controller;

    public void Init(Controller controller){
        this.controller = controller;
        controller.DataChanged += PrintDelta; // error: cannot be assigned to as it's readonly
    }

    public void PrintDelta(float delta){  
        Console.WriteLine(delta);
    }
}
```

As shown above, I've tried defining the delegate as a readonly property. However, this doesn't work. I'm trying to use the get and set successors like below but I'm unsure what to put in for the set. Any ideas?

Get/Set:
`public Action<float> DataChanged { get{ return data.ValueChanged } set{ //don't know what to put here }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is

```
public Action<float> DataChanged
{
   get => data.ValueChanged;
   set { data.ValueChanged = value; }
}
```

But this is generally the wrong thing to do, as it can't forward an event.

Using an explicitly-implemented event is compatible whether the underlying is an event, field, or property:

```
public event Action<float> DataChanged
{
   add { data.ValueChanged += value; }
   remove { data.ValueChanged -= value; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Using the explicitly-implemented event was the solution I was looking for.